# QML override item style

Tags: qt, combobox, qml

Is it possible to override only one property of style, for example, combobox?

```
ComboBox {
        id: comboBox

        anchors.fill: parent

        style: ComboBoxStyle {
            label: Component {
               Text {
                    text: "Players -> " + comboBox.currentText
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In KDE this combobox looks ugly because it does not use kde theme style and uses default's one.

ComboBox with overriden styles and without style override:
[image: ComboBox with overriden styles and without style override]

I need to have a combobox styled like last one on this image but with custom text.

Comment: Which property do you want to override? a label?

Comment: Yes, a label in this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want native look and feel with custom behaviour.

You cannot acheive this out-of-the box with QtQuick Controls 1 or 2 as mentionned in this [Qt mailing list post](http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/development/2014-April/016656.html).

You may be able to get a native style with Qt Widgets, but in addition to the added work with Qt Widgets, I don't know if you can get a themed native style…

You can wait for Qt 6 CommonControls as mentionned here : http://blog.qt.io/blog/2017/02/06/native-look-feel/ but it won't allow you to customize much, as stated in the post.